Кроссбраузерность для бекграунд фотографии
У меня есть бекграунд фотография, которая остается на месте в то время как остальной контент скролится по ней, но проблема в том, что на ios, она не подстраивается под эти стили, может есть какой-то другой способ или команды для таких случаев?
.page_body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 //Background-image - висит на тэге body


А в каком ios имеется такая проблема?вы покажите код на реальном сервере...я посмотрю на айфоне, макбуке и на аймаке...планки с айосом нету ...

Начиная с iOS 15.8.2 и выше

https://u9on.github.io/our_wedding/

Очень странно, поскольку данная проблема согласно документации была решена начиная с > Safari 15.4
Я тоже когда-то сталкивался с похожей проблемой, но тогда это было критично и я решал через JS и фиксировал изображение на тег <img>.
Ещё можете попробовать.


function supportsFixedBackground() {
  try {
    var style = document.body.style;
    if (!("backgroundAttachment" in style)) return false;
    var oldValue = style.backgroundAttachment;
    style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
    var isSupported = (style.backgroundAttachment === "fixed");
    style.backgroundAttachment = oldValue;
    return isSupported;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url('https://u9on.github.io/our_wedding/images/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation-name: visible;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

div {
  height: 500vh;
}
<div></div>




А для чего тут div, если не сложно, можете объяснить?

для примера... это не принциально. Без него скрола не будет. Лучше забудьте про использование фоновых изображений, если про продуктивность сайта думаете. Используйте тег <picture> потом пойменет зачем. Удобнее не значит правильнее...
